# How to use ObjectInputStream to find a class instance in a list of instances

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am trying to create an instance of the class `Account` and it cannot have the same `handle` as other accounts, which is checked using a for loop which compares the `handle` passed a parameter to the handles of the existing accounts, if it already exists then the exception `IllegalHandleException` is thrown

How do you go from having the read file to the list of the accounts, i.e. what needs to replace `//listOfaccounts=list of each account` before the for loop

```java
public int createAccount(String handle) throws IllegalHandleException{
    //checks if handle is already taken
    FileInputStream accountsFile=new FileInputStream("listOfAccounts.txt");
    ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(accountsFile);

    //listOfAccounts=list of each account 

    for (Account accounts : listOfAccounts){
        if (handle==accounts.getHandle()){
            throw new IllegalHandleException("Handle Is Already Taken");
        }
    }

    //create account
    Account newAccount;
    newAccount=new Account(handle);

    //add account to the stream
    FileOutputStream updatedAccountsFile=new FileOutputStream("listOfAccounts.txt");
    updatedAccountsFile.write(newAccount.getUserID());
    ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(updatedAccountsFile);

    //return ID 
    return newAccount.getUserID();
}
```

Comment: Using the extension `.txt` for data used in combination with `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` is suspicious, because `.txt` implies textual data, while `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` use a **binary** serialization format.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel done some more reading so should it be a `.ser` file?

Comment: *if (handle==accounts.getHandle())* that, btw, is wrong. `String.equals` is used to compare strings in Java

Comment: @g00se so ```if (handle.equals(accounts.getHandle()))``` ?

Comment: Not sure what your question is there (or even if there *is* one), but if the (corrected) statement you've just written equals true, in your previous code, it could easily equal false for the same value

Comment: @g00se original question was what needs to replace the comment above the for loop, i.e. how do I go from the file to having a list that can be looped through

Comment: I was just making a side comment really, but since your main question seems to be unanswered for you, you should write `List<Account>` with your oos and read that with your ois, making it simple to then search for `Account`s to remove, or whatever

Comment: There is not an "official" extension for serialized objects. Some use .ser, some use .dat, others use .bin, etc, etc.